# Return array of doubles using stream() and map() in Java 8

Tags: java

I have a class called `FileDb` and within it is the property which holds a list of objects of type `ParamAnalysis`:

```
public class FileDb {
    private List<ParamAnalysis> paramsAnaylsis;
```

`ParamAnalysis` holds a bunch of values which are of type `double`:

```
public class ParamAnalysis {
    double max;
    double min;
    ...
```

I want to get all the 'maxes' in the list paramsAnaylsis. So I'm doing:

```
public static double[] getMaxesFromDb(FileDb fileDb){
    return fileDb.getParamsAnaylsis().stream().map(paramAnalysis -> Double.valueOf(paramAnalysis.getMax())).toArray();
}
```

But I send up with the error:

```
Error:(35, 120) java: incompatible types: java.lang.Object[] cannot be converted to double[]
```

How can I get an array of doubles back from this method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using `mapToDouble` to receive a `DoubleStream` and finish with a `toArray()`. The reason you receive the exception is because, even though you're converting to a `Double`, it still is an object.

```
fileDb.getParamsAnaylsis()
      .stream()
      .mapToDouble(paramAnalysis -> paramAnalysis.getMax()) <-- creates a stream of primitive doubles
      .toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `Stream.toArray()` that returns `Object[]`.
To type the array, you could use the overload `<A> A[] toArray(IntFunction<A[]> generator);` that returns a array of the type specified by the `IntFunction` but it will return a array of `Double` and you want an array of `double`.

The best thing to do is using `mapToDouble()` to unbox `Double` to `double` via a `DoubleStream`.  You could so use `DoubleStream.toArray()` that returns `double[]`.

```
public static double[] getMaxesFromDb(FileDb fileDb){
    return fileDb.getParamsAnaylsis()
                 .stream()  // Stream<ParamAnalysis>
                 .mapToDouble(p -> p.getMax()) //DoubleStream
                 .toArray(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `mapToDouble` instead of `map`.

`double` is a primitive type and therefore does not extend `Object`. The return type of `map` something that extends `Object`. To circumvent this limitation, Java provides `mapToXX` (e.g. `mapToDouble`) for all primitive types, which do not return a `Stream<?>` but a `XXStream` (e.g. a `DoubleStream`) instead.

Another option would be to make your `getMaxesFromDb` return an array of `Double` (uppercase) as it is an object type.